# Remover da formatação moeda o ponto e vírgula por espaço em branco - PHP

Tags: php

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte código para remover os pontos e a vírgula:

```
$valor = str_replace("." , "" , $valor );
$valor = str_replace("," , "" , $valor);
```

Há como fazer isso em um único código, sem primeiro fazer uma coisa depois outra?

Procurei e não encontrei uma solução para também remover os dois últimos zeros.

**Exemplo:**
300.000,00
**Resultado:** 300000

Comment: Se as casas decimais forem diferentes de zero, você ainda vai jogá-las fora sem fazer arredondamento?

Comment: Não tem haverá valores diferentes de zero, pois são valores de imóveis.

Comment: para tirar o ponto e a vírgula, se não me engano o str_replace aceita arrays na entrada, então ficaria "str_replace([".", ","] , ["", ""] , $valor );", acredito que assim resumiria em uma linha a remoção desses caracteres.

Comment: @Ruggi este código está com erro.

Comment: Tem Razão @GladisonNeuzaPerosini, corrigido.

Comment: O erro desaparecei, mas quando executo ele dá erro. Mostra o seguinte: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: Como faço para remover os dois últimos zeros?

Comment: A código no comentário do  Ruggi usa alias de array, o qual é disponível a partir do php 5.5. Para tornar compatível, use `str_replace(array('.', ','), '', $valor);`

Comment: No título diz "espaço em branco". Porém, "espaço em branco" é diferente de "vazio". Acho que pretende remover trocando por vazio.

Comment: realmente o @daniel-omine tem razão, utilize o que o daniel disse para substituir a pontuação, depois retire os últimos dois zeros, dessa maneira: $valor = substr($valor, 0, -2);

Comment: realizei a execução do código sem erros, ficou desse jeito:

$valor = "300.000,00";

echo $valor."</br>";

$valor = str_replace(Array(",", "."), "", $valor);

echo $valor. "</br>";

$valor = substr($valor, 0, -2 );

echo $valor;

Comment: @Ruggi eu utilizo no mysql o campo tipo float para moedas, está correto?

Comment: @Ruggi sempre que eu gravo no banco ele elimina alguns zeros. Tipo, se eu gravo 300000 ele armazena apenas 300. Já perdi a noção do que pode estar acontecendo.

Comment: meu, assim, quando se grava tipo float no mysql, a separação de decimal dele deve ser com ".". então te aconselho a não tirar os dois últimos... e adicionar o ponto no local correto, você viu o post que marcaram que são duplicadas as respostas? tentou gravar no banco daquela maneira?